# Qual é a diferença entre %d e %i no printf e no scanf, na linguagem C?

Tags: c

Qual é a diferença entre %d e %i no **printf** e no **scanf**, na linguagem C?

Answer (score 3):

- São interpretados iguais no `printf`, escolhe o que preferir.
- No `scanf` é que as coisas são diferentes.

O `%d` apenas reconhece numeros de **base 10**

O `%i` aceita **octal** (prefixo `0`) e **hexadecimal** (prefixo `0x`)

> 250 -> decimal
>
> 0250 -> octal
>
> 0x250 -> hexadecimal